# Very hard question for me

Tags: partial-differential-equations

Let $\Omega$ be an open bounded subset of $R^n$, and let $\partial \Omega$ denote its boundary. Let $u$ $\in$ $C^2(\Omega$) $\cap$ $C(\overline \Omega$) be a solution of the Dirichlet problem.

$-\Delta$ u(x) + $\sum_{k=1}^n$$a_{k}(x)u_{x_k}(x)+h(u(x))=f(x)$ in $\Omega$,

$u(x)=g(x)$ on $\partial \Omega$

where $a_k$, $f \in C(\Omega$), $g \in C(\partial \Omega$), $h \in C(R)$ satisfy:
f(x) $\le 0 $ $\forall$ $x \in \Omega$ ; g(x) $ \le 0$ $\forall$ $x \in \partial \Omega$; $h(0)=0$, xh(x) $\gt 0$ if $x \neq 0$.Prove that u(x) $\le 0 $ $\forall x \in \overline \Omega$.

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

Since $u$ is continuous on the compact set $\overline\Omega$ it attains its supremum at some $x_0\in\overline\Omega$. If $u(x_0)\leq0$ we are done, so assume now that $u(x_0)>0$. Then $x_0$ is an inner point of $\Omega$, $x_0$ is a local maximum of $u$, hence $\nabla u(x_0)=0$ and $\Delta u(x_0)\leq0$. Then we have $h(u(x_0))>0$ and therefore
$$
0\geq f(x_0)=-\Delta u(x_0)+\langle (a_k)(x_0),\nabla u(x_0)\rangle+h(u(x_0))>0,
$$
a contradiction.

Comment: you're welcome :)